# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime with value '#N/A'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a usecase where I want to take date of one collumn (2014/07/07) and time from another collumn of other table (8:00:00) but it is showing error while converting it.

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
```

below is the query I used

```
select convert(datetime,convert(nvarchar(16),convert(nvarchar(8),r.eta)+' '+convert(nvarchar(7),m.[msps code time]))) from rawdata_master r join msps_port_code m on r.rkst=m.[gsis to port] where r.eta not like '&nbsp'
and m.[msps code time] not like '#N/A'
```

the second collumn from which I am taking time part have value like  '#N/A'. Please help me out.

Comment: Your problem is here: `convert(nvarchar(8),r.eta) + ' ' + convert(nvarchar(7),m.[msps code time]))`.  I assume you are trying to concat a date value and a time value, but if you are having to restrict values like `#N/A` then i'd suggest you have other bad values in your data.

Comment: In the given collumn there are blank spaces and #N/A values . I am not getting what filters should I use

Comment: @paqogomez When I went through the log I found that when converting value less than 12:00:00 it is okay but the row having value 13:00:00 is not converting it

Comment: There can be other values which cause overflow and not just your N/A

Comment: It Works I have given nvarchar length 1 less than actual date nvarchar(9) works for date

Comment: select 
--convert(datetime,convert(nvarchar(18),convert(nvarchar(8),r.eta)+' '+convert(nvarchar(8),m.[msps code time]))) 
convert(datetime,convert(nvarchar, convert(nvarchar(18),convert(nvarchar(9),r.eta))+' '+convert(nvarchar(8),m.[msps code time])))
from rawdata_master r join msps_port_code m on r.rkst=m.[gsis to port] 
where m.[msps code time] not in ('#N/A','#NAME?','#REF!')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer . change from `nvarchar(8)` to `nvarchar(9)`

```
select convert(datetime,convert(nvarchar(18),convert(nvarchar(9),r.eta)+'
'+convert(nvarchar(9),m.[msps code time]))) convert(datetime,convert(nvarchar, 
convert(nvarchar(18),convert(nvarchar(9),r.eta))+' '+convert(nvarchar(9),
m.[msps code time]))) from rawdata_master r join msps_port_code m on r.rkst=
m.[gsis to port] where m.[msps code time] not in ('#N/A','#NAME?','#REF!')
```